# Why is this test junit test returning a 400?

Tags: java, unit-testing, post, junit, mockito

I have a controller that looks like:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/email", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public String  notification(@RequestBody EmailNotificationRequest emailNotificationRequest) throws IOException {
    String jobId = emailNotificationRequest.getJobId();
    try {
        service.jobId(jobId);
        return jobId;

    } catch (ApplicationException e) {
        return "failed to send email to for jobId: " + jobId;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to test the controller but getting a 400 back:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(emailNotificationController).build();
}

@Test
public void successfulServiceCallShouldReturn200() throws Exception {

    String request = "{\"jobId\" : \"testId\"}";

    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(post("/email")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json(request))
            .andReturn();

    String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

    assertThat(content, isNotNull());

}
```

Now I realize that 400 means the request is bad. So I tried making my own request and then turning it to a JSON string like so:

```
@Test
public void successfulServiceCallShouldReturn200() throws Exception {
    EmailNotificationRequest emailNotificationRequest = new emailNotificationRequest();
    emailNotificationRequest.setJobId("testJobId");

    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(post("/notification/email")
            .content(asJsonString(emailNotificationRequest))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    assertThat(result, isNotNull());

}

public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
    try {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        final String jsonContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        return jsonContent;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the content() since i am getting 400 and that has to do with the actual request. Can someone please tell me why the request is still bad here? Or a better way to test this particular POST method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add `accept("application/json"))`

Comment: Hi @Jens thank you for the response. I added that to both my attempts at a test and now am getting a null pointer exception. But that is at least a different error! Thank you.

Comment: I have added it as answer. Feel free to accept and/or upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `accept("application/json"))`.

If not the mock does not accept this content type.